# child div will not show its background color unless it is populated

Tags: css

I am trying to create a little element graph.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
div .row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
div .row .col4 {
  padding-right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
}
.myGraph {
  background: #208FBF;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col4">
      <span class="myGraph">will show</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
      <span class="myGraph"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
      <span class="myGraph"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that only the myGraph element that is populated will show a background color.
why is this happening? i want the myGraph class to have always a background color.

Thanks

Comment: `span`s do not have a height by default. When there is no content the `height` will be `0`, so it will not have a body.

Comment: if i now add a few spans in each column and add height to the graph it will not be alligned properly with the other spans

Comment: What do you mean by aligned?

Comment: it will be a little above the other spans near it, but if i put text inside it, it will return to be exactly as the other spans. why is this happening?

Comment: I don't really get it. You want to have `myGraph` to be `100%` wide, right? Perhaps you could make `myGraph` `display: block`. Btw, I think you can get rid of the `width: 100%;` when elements are `display: block`.

Comment: Let me correct:
i have:
<div class="col4">info:</div>
<div class="col4"><div class="myGraph"></div></div>
<div clas="col4">number</div>

the problem is that without having some text inside the "myGraph" the column will be painted with color but will not be alligned (will be a bit above) the other columns

Comment: Hmm, could you provide a fiddle? I would go with "display: block" property for span elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications on your code:

style.css

```
  html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

div .row .col4 {
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 30%;
    background: #Fa1;
}

div .row .full-charge { 
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.myGraph {
       min-width:0%;
       background: #aa1;
       display: inline-block;
}
```

index.html

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col4">
            <span class="myGraph" style="width:50%">
              <div class="full-charge">
              </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col4">
            <span class="myGraph" style="width:80%">
               <div class="full-charge">
               </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col4" style="background: #Fa1;">
            <div class="myGraph" style="width:20%">
              <div class="full-charge">
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/G0tjLubUYcNWepXCbKgH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Default height is 0, if you have no content there... insert a text, or entity  , or picture, or give a height to div and you will see